# Re-sorting a multi-dimensional object

Tags: javascript, sorting, oop, object

I should sort a multidimensional object, according to the index of a dimension, but also keeping the corresponding indices.

ACTUAL OBJECT STRUCTURE

```
object1[index1][index2][index3][index4][index5]
```

SORTING PRIORITY AT PRESENT (OBIVIOUSLY)

```
1st
[index1]
2nd
[index2]
3rd
[index3]
4th
[index4]
5th
[index5]
```

EXAMPLE (SORTING AT PRESENT)

```
1st - object1['1']['50']['0']['0.00']['ARTICOLO3']
2nd - object1['1']['51']['0']['0.00']['ARTICOLO2']
3rd - object1['1']['52']['0']['0.00']['ARTICOLO1']
```

RE-SORTING EXPECTED

```
1st
[index4]
2th
[index5]
3rd
[index3]
4th
[index1]
5th
[index2]
```

EXAMPLE (RE-SORTING BY INDEX5)

```
1st - object1['1']['52']['0']['0.00']['ARTICOLO1']
2nd - object1['1']['51']['0']['0.00']['ARTICOLO2']
3rd - object1['1']['50']['0']['0.00']['ARTICOLO3']
```

Comment: Javascript objects don't have any order. You need to use an array if order matters.

Comment: do you have an object containing nested objects or an array of objects? Any chance to get the original piece of code including the input object?

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.sort` with a comparison function that compares the index that you want.

Comment: What is the actual data structure? I have never heard of a multi-dimensional object before.

Comment: The ordering of objects in a JS object is unreliable (there is a lot to it). So what you think is "the current order" of your object might not always be true. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: @briosheje probably you have reason. it should be a nested object, and i need to re-sort it according to various necessity.

Comment: @DavideCaballeros: It would be nice to share such an object or the source of it, else it will be quite hard to help you, because as long as we don't have a proper source it's pretty senseless to spend time writing code that may be useless to you ;)

Comment: @epascarello you can look the actual structure at "EXAMPLE (SORTING AT PRESENT)"

Comment: That is not valid JavaScript, what is the actual JavaScript code for the object/data. I am trying to determine if it is an array with objects, or an object with objects. Depending on that, there are two answers...